# Was bedeutet „vom Flur aus in Bewegung setzen”?

Tags: translation, technical-terminology

Wisst ihr, was der Satz *Das Fahrzeug nicht vom „Flur“ aus in Bewegung setzen.* bedeutet? Das ist ein Abschnitt aus einer Anweisung, in der manche Regeln für die Arbeit mit Gabelstaplern und Baggern aufgelistet wurden.

Vielen Dank im Voraus.

Comment: Was sollen die Anführungsstriche um Flur? Sind die im Original?

Comment: Bitte mehr Kontext. - Mit "Flur" könnte der Werkshallenboden gemeint sein (floor oder auch shop floor auf Englisch), aber ohne mehr Kontext... hm...

Comment: Ja, die stehen im Original.

Comment: Worin besteht das Problem? Ein Flur ist ein Gang zwischen Zimmerfluchten. Und weil solche Gänge meistens schmal sind, könnte ein Gabelstapler beim Anfahren leicht gegen die Wände oder Regale stoßen.

Comment: Das ergibt für mich trotzdem nicht viel Sinn. Erstens: Ein Gablerstapler mag in Werksfluren herumfahren. Aber ein Bagger? Zweitens: Warum sollte ich einen Gabelstapler nicht vom Flur aus in Bewegung setzen (sprich: anfahren, wegfahren)? Und was mache ich, wenn er dort nun einmal steht? Wie kriege ich ihn dann da wieder weg, ohne ihn in Bewegung zu setzen? - Nee, dieser Satz braucht deutlich mehr Kontext.

Comment: Mehr Kontext habe ich leider nicht. Das ist nur eine Liste, die mehrere Regeln beinhaltet, die die Bedienung von Fahrzeugen anbetreffen. Bevor steht: Unnötiges Laufenlassen des Motors vermeiden. und dann: Vorm Verlassen des Fahrzeuges die Feststellbremse anziehen und den Schlüssel abziehen. Diese Sätze sind offensichtlich miteinander nicht verbunden.

Comment: Dir fehlt die Vorstellungskraft :-) Glaube mir, genau das ist damit gemeint. Der Oberbegriff ist übrigens _Flurförderfahrzeug_.

Comment: Der Satz steht tatsächlich so (allerdings ohne Anführungszeichen) in Betriebsanweisungen für Gabelstapler, bis hin zu den offiziellen Mustern der [DGUV](http://publikationen.dguv.de/dguv/pdf/10002/bgi578.pdf).

Comment: Damit könnte die Position des Fahrers gemeint sein: Gabelstapler haben ja keine Türen, also könnte man neben dem Stapler stehen und die Hebel (z. B. zum Heben und Senken der Gabel) bedienen. Die Forderung besagt, dass man im Gabelstapler sitzen soll, wenn man ihn nutzt.

Comment: @IQV: Das ist nicht vorstellbar. Ob mit abgesenkter Gabel oder erhobener - "in Bewegung setzen" drückt nicht nur eines von beiden aus.

Comment: Tja. Hier steht es in der Tat genauso drin: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjHuqDo1bPVAhVG7hoKHQbDBXkQFggwMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bgn-fleischwirtschaft.de%2Ffileadmin%2Fuser_upload%2Fdoc%2Fsicherheit%2Fschwerpunktaktionen%2Frisiko_raus%2FBetriebsanweisung_Gabelstapler_Gasantrieb.doc&usg=AFQjCNE-nI9BzTgAEGiwH4RghKEvOwJGog  Offenbar weiß der Gabelstaplerfahrer, was damit gemeint ist (im Gegensatz zum Normalmenschen). Achtung, Durchsage: Befindet sicht unter den Mitlesern ein  Gabelstaplerfahrer?

Comment: +1 für @IQV. Dementsprechend lautet auch eine der Prüfungsfragen in der theoretischen Prüfung "Warum dürfen Flurförderzeuge mit Fahrerstand oder -sitz nicht vom Boden aus in Bewegung gesetzt werden?"

Comment: Ich bin übrigens der Meinung, dass der "offizielle" Begriff *Flurförderzeug* nichts mit dem "Hausflur" oder den Fluren zwischen den Hochregallagern zu tun hat, sondern von "die Flur" (wie in "Wald und Flur"), also "Boden" kommt - Die Begriffserklärung in den DIN-Normen spricht von "Förderfahrzeugen, die bodenläufig sind" (und fasst darunter auch Gabelstapler, die man auf dem Acker zum Apfelkisten stapeln nutzt, also ganz ohne Flure). Damit müsste es eigentlich richtig heißen: "Fahrzeug nicht von *der Flur* aus in Bewegung setzen"

Comment: @tofro: Wenn du mal beim DWDS nachschaust, siehst du, dass auch _der Flur_ den Boden meint und das Geschlecht erst seit dem 14. Jh. unterschieden wird. Also bleiben wir doch einfach bei _dem Flur_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich glaube nicht, dass wir uns heute mit der Grammatik des 14. Jahrhunderts  rumschlagen sollten. Zu unsrer Zeit gibt's "der Flur" und "die Flur" (außerdem noch Adjektive wie "unterflur" und "oberflur"). Und ich bestehe darauf, dass Gabelstapler nicht in meinem Hausflur fahren.

Comment: @tofro: Das habe ich auch nicht gemeint. Ich glaube auch, wie du, dass es um den _Boden_ geht. Allerdings ist der auch in der heutigen Zeit _der Flur_. Lediglich der _landwirtschaftliche Boden_ ist _die Flur_.

Answer (score 4):

Die Vorschrift betrifft m.E. eine bestimmte Gruppe von Flurfördergeräten, nämlich solche mit Fahrersitz oder Fahrerstand. Flurfördergeräte gibt es in verschiedenen Ausführungen, etwa als einfache Handhubwagen, bei denen der Nutzer auf dem Boden steht oder geht und den Hubwagen zieht oder schiebt. Daneben gibt es Ausführungen, bei denen der Nutzer auf dem Fahrzeug steht oder sitzt.

Bei solchen Fahrzeugen mit Fahrersitz oder -stand darf der Nutzer das Gefährt nur dann in Bewegung setzen, wenn er - bei stillstehendem Fahrzeug - bereits auf dem Fahrersitz oder -stand Platz genommen hat. Anderenfalls ist nicht gewährleistet, dass er die volle Kontrolle über das - in der Regel beladene - Fahrzeug behält, wenn es erst einmal in Bewegung ist.

Geregelt ist das in § 16 der Unfallverhütungsvorschrift DGUV Nr. 68 (vormals BGV D27):

> § 16
>   Verhalten während des Betriebes
>
> (1) Der Fahrer darf Flurförderzeuge nur von den bestimmungsgemäß vorgesehenen Steuerplätzen aus steuern. (...)
>
> (3) Versicherte dürfen nur bei stillstehendem Flurförderzeug auf- oder absteigen.

Der Satz *Das Fahrzeug nicht vom „Flur“ aus in Bewegung setzen* dient wie die übrigen Verhaltensregeln (als Muster für eine Betriebsanweisung gemäß § 12 BetrSichV) dazu, diese Unfallverhütungsvorschrift schlagwortartig in Erinnerung zu rufen. Er richtet sich zudem an bereits instruiertes Personal. In diesem Fall ist die knappe "Befehlsform" sowohl sinnvoll als auch ausreichend.